How to cover existing moldy shower knob
any suggestions how to cover à moldy shower knob which is difficult to replace and maintenance is reluctant to make further attempt to replace it. I inherited this unslightly situation.

Can you provide a picture of the situation?

You don't cover.  You clean with bleach using another's toothbrush, or if a nice person buy a new toothbrush to use.

@crip659, funny but , ouch.  Makes me think of someone that said, "always be nice to anyone who has axcess to your toothbrush."  I bet it's a moen type of semi-clear knob that gets grimey inside.
